# Neo4j: creating relationships between existing subgraphs is very slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When creating relationships between existing nodes (see Q1 below) (on indexed properties) I see roughly 24000 ops/sec. However, when I match the same nodes but this time including subgraphs (Q2), the performance drops to about 9000 ops/sec. I'm not sure whether this is an actual bug, or whether I'm misinterpreting the way I believe Cypher should work.

Q1 (performs at about 24000 ops/sec)

```
UNWIND {batch} AS rel
    MATCH (c1:ChildA {key: rel.akey})
    MATCH (c2:ChildB {key: rel.bkey})
    CREATE (c1)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(c2)
```

Q2 (performs at about 9000 ops/sec)

```
UNWIND {batch} AS rel
    MATCH
        (p1:ParentA {key: 'Chris'})
        <-[:BELONGS_TO]-
        (c1:ChildA {key: rel.akey})
    MATCH
        (p2:ParentB {key: 'Zoe'})
        <-[:BELONGS_TO]-
        (c2:ChildB {key: rel.bkey})
    CREATE (c1)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(c2)
```

Edit 12-02-2019 7:48am: added Profile query plans

[Q1 profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJSXN.png)

[Q2 profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK8Lk.png)

Comment: You may want to PROFILE both queries. Keep in mind the first query doesn't do any property access, just index lookups and the relationship creation. The second query may be using index lookups for one node each in the pattens, but it must expand and them perform property access and filtering. We may be able to tweak this and use multiple index lookups and avoid property access completely, but it would help to see the PROFILE plan first (with all elements expanded)

Comment: thanks! I added the Profile results, quite curious to see if we can improve it!

Comment: The query plans look fine. Do you have query logging enabled (this is an enterprise-only feature), that could show you where the time is being spent on queries, and whether page cache hits or misses are involved. You may also want to run `neo4j-admin memrec` to get a memory configuration recommendation based on the memory on your system.